# PyCharm not recognizing PyQT4 and PyQt4 not allowing me to 'view code'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pycharm

I am a beginner and have 2 issues, which may be related to each other.
1. I am using PyCharm, and when I put
    "from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic"
I get a red line under each word (except from & import) saying "unresolved reference".

2. I have PyQ4/Designer installed (I know it is because I have made a GUI), but when I click 'view code' for the GUI, it says "unable to launch C:/Python34/Lib/site-packages/PyQt4\uic"

Maybe a path issue???  Like I said, I am very new to Python/Qt and really do not know how to check the path and/or change it if it is wrong.  I downloaded Python 3.6.0, PyChamr2016.3.2, Qt4.8.7

Comment: It sounds to me that you only installed Qt, not PyQt. How did you install PyQt? Furthremore, it's better to ask only one question per post (make a separate post if necessary).

Comment: As I remember, I downloaded them from the Py qt website (its been a few months so I forget, you may be right).  How do I check if I only installed Qt, and not PyQt?

Comment: Ok, after checking my start menu, I have several applications under PyQt GPL V4.11 for python, including assistant/designer/homepage/linguist/pyqt book, pyqt class references, etc.  Does that mean I have PyQt??  - all from Riverbank software

Comment: You probably do have PyQt then.The best way to check is to start Python and type `from PyQt4 import QtCore`. You'll get an error if PyQt is not installed correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you *do* seem to have PyQt installed my guess is that you have multiple Python versions installed (version 3.4 and version 3.6) and that PyQt is only installed under 3.6, but that PyCharm and the Designer are configured to use 3.4.

I don't know how to change the Python interpreter in the Qt Designer as I never use it. However in PyCharm open the settings and look for the "Project Interpeter" tab. There you can configure the default Python interpreter that is used for your project. It even shows the installed packages for that interpreter.

When you run a Python program from PyCharm, the first line in the output shows which Python interpreter was used. This way you can check if it is as expected. If it is still not correct, it can be that you have overridden it in your *Run Configuration*. Select "Edit Configuration" from the "Run" menu. This will open a dialog with *Run Configuration* settings for the Python script that you last executed. Check the "Python Interpreter" there and change it if needed.

Comment: When I open the Python command window, it says Python 3.6.0.  When I type in "from PyQt4 import Qtcore" is says "Module not found - no module named PyQt4.  When I run my program in PyCharm, the first line says C:\Users.........Python36\python.exe......."  At one point I did have an earlier version of Python installed (forgot what version), but someone told me it was a beta version and to install 3.6.

Comment: Lastly, I looked in my program listing and saw that I have PyQT GPL for Python v3.4.  Does that mean I need to uninstall PyQt for Python 3.4 and install PyQt for Python 3.6????

Comment: No, you don't have to uninstall PyQt4 for Python 3.4, you can just install for 3.6. Luckily this has become easier since Python 3.5. You can install it with `pip install PyQt4`. Check that you have the pip that belongs to Python 3.6 with `pip --version`

Comment: BTW, if you have installed Python with the [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/) distribution you must install PyQt4 with `conda install pyqt=4`. If you don't know what the Anaconda distribution is, disregards this comment.

Comment: in the python command window, it says "name 'pip' not defined"

Comment: Pip is a stand-alone program. You have to start if from the regular command prompt (`cmd`)

Comment: I opened a Windows command window, typed in "pip --version", and got "pip not recognized".  I then typed in python in the windows command window, then "pip --version", and got "pip not defined"

Comment: That's because it's not in one of the directories listed in the Windows `Path` environment variable. It is probably located in the same directory as your `python.exe` executable. Find it and, either start it with its full path name (so something like `C:\Users.........Python36\pip`), or add this directory to the Path environment variable, as explained [here](https://github.com/Langoor2/PokemonGo-Map-FAQ/wiki/'python---pip'-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command,-operable-program-or-batch-file.)

Comment: In the windows cmd window, I entered "pip install PyQt4", it displayed "Collecting PyQt4", then came back with "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyQt4 (from versions: ) No matching distributions found for PyQt4

Comment: Not sure what's wrong here. Are you sure you have the correct pip? What does `pip --version` say?

Comment: I really appreciate all of your help.  pip version 9.0.1 from C:\python36\lib\site-packages (python 3.6). If you do not have time to continue with me, I understand.